# Why WP with Z3 proves \false when access to struct field is defined?

Tags: frama-c

I've written simple ACSL contract for two C functions:

```
struct S
{
    int n;
};

/*@ axiomatic Block {
    predicate isZero(int left) =
        left == 0;

    // Unused, but necessary for verification
    logic int getN(struct S *s) = s->n;
}*/

/*@ requires \valid(s);
    requires isZero(s->n);
    assigns \nothing;
    ensures \false; // Verified by Z3
*/
void g(struct S *s)
{
}

/*@ assigns \nothing;
    ensures \false; // Verified by Z3
*/
void f()
{
    struct S s;
    s.n = 0;
    g(&s);
}
```

As you can see, specifications establish that `f()` and `g()` ensure obviously false statement. The problem is in verification of `g()`, I've defined `f()` to show that preconditions of `g()` can be satisfied. Why Z3 manages to prove both contracts if logic function `getN` is defined?

I've launched this example in docker container that uses Ubuntu 20.04 to ensure that problem isn't caused by my environment. Frama-C version: 27.1 (Cobalt). Z3 version 4.12.2 - 64 bit.

In a shell:

```
CMD eval $(opam env --switch=4.14.1) && why3 --version && frama-c --version && z3 --version && frama-c -wp -rte -wp-prover="z3" -wp-timeout 100 /tmp/acsl/acsl.c
```

produces

```
Why3 platform, version 1.6.0
27.1 (Cobalt)
Z3 version 4.12.2 - 64 bit
[kernel] Parsing tmp/acsl/acsl.c (with preprocessing)
[rte:annot] annotating function f
[rte:annot] annotating function g
[wp] Running WP plugin...
[wp] 9 goals scheduled
[wp] Proved goals:    9 / 9
  Qed:             7
  Z3 4.12.2:       2
```

The problem may be in Z3 itself, because Alt-Ergo and CVC4 cannot prove these goals.

I've also reproduced this example in `framac/frama-c:dev` container from Docker hub. I've used this Dockerfile:

```
FROM framac/frama-c:dev
RUN wget https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases/download/z3-4.12.2/z3-4.12.2-x64-glibc-2.31.zip
RUN unzip z3-4.12.2-x64-glibc-2.31.zip
RUN sudo cp z3-4.12.2-x64-glibc-2.31/bin/z3 /usr/local/bin/z3
RUN why3 config detect
RUN mkdir /tmp/acsl
CMD why3 --version && frama-c --version && z3 --version && frama-c -wp -rte -wp-prover="z3" -wp-timeout 100 /tmp/acsl/acsl.c
```

Comment: what's your version of Why3? I have 1.6.0 and I cannot reproduce the issue (i.e. z3 fails on g's ensures)

Comment: Strange, I have 1.6.0 too. What else can I check?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the `-wp-timeout 100` at the end of your command line. Indeed, if I let z3 running for longer time, I reproduce the behavior you observe.